# Explanation of Android Code Camera Intent + Cropping Images

Tags: android, android-camera, crop, android-camera-intent, resize-crop

When wanting to take a photo, crop and save the image in an Android application, I use the following intent in my Java...

```
            Intent camera=new Intent();
            camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            camera.putExtra("crop", "true");
            camera.putExtra("outputX",600);
            camera.putExtra("outputY", 600);
            camera.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            camera.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            camera.putExtra("scale", true);
            camera.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

The above intent works great, however my Y and X are always equal. I am looking to break down the code to find out what specifies this so that I can make customisable - and most importantly independent - X and Y values for the image which I have taken and wish to crop...

Comment: For the third time in the past 24 hours, **there is no crop `Intent` in Android**: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: I believe you are incoreect...

simply try it on its own in API 8+ (this is only where i have tested) `camera.putExtra("crop", "true");` squares off the image | `camera.putExtra("crop", "false");` will leave the image as its default aspect ratio...

Comment: There is no guarantee, whatsoever, that every Android device (let alone third-party `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` apps) will honor these undocumented `Intent` extras and perform some sort of cropping action.

Comment: so is this device specific? or application specific, what handles this intent to tell it what to do...

Comment: if were saying its not guarenteed to behave in a particular way in every app/device, then what and where is its behavious currently definded... Thanks for the heads up by the way CommonsWare it's useful stuff to know and talk about !!

Comment: This `Intent` aims to start up an activity. That activity is part of an app. There can be zero, one, or several apps on the device that have an activity that honors this `Intent` action. Apps can be pre-installed or installed by the user. There is no requirement that any `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` app supports cropping via these `Intent` extras. So, if a device manufacturer skipped them, or a user installed a third-party app that skipped them, you are out of luck. Do not rely on undocumented `Intent` extras -- use a library.

Comment: In terms of what is and is not documented, if you find yourself putting in `Intent` extras, where the keys are just bare strings, not defined as constants somewhere in the framework (e.g., on `MediaStore`), then they are not documented.

Comment: Supposedly this is because an OS update could render them no longer valid? which would cause either loss of functionality, or more likely a crash...

Comment: "this is because an OS update could render them no longer valid?" -- that's one possibility. Or, the user downloads an app and chooses to use it for your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, and that app does not support cropping. Or the device never had a cropping-enabled `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity. Unless you are planning on using a nuclear device to hold the world's developers hostage and force them to bend to your will and implement universal support for cropping with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, please use a library. Note that hostage-taking is illegal in many jurisdictions.

Comment: Thumbs up to your whit... Made me chuckle ! Ok right i am totally with you now. Time to try out some alternatives and get back to the drawing board. Thanks :)

Comment: do you know what `("return-data", false); ` provides? Noob here ;)

Comment: Aren't the default Android "Camera" app same across all Android devices. Does it not support these cropping intents?

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE : THE USE OF `camera.putExtra("crop", "true");` IS NOT ADVISED...** See Comments above for details... The aspect parts did however fix my issues !

```
            Intent camera=new Intent();

            /** This specifies the action for this intent when it is called. */
            camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            /** This says yes we can crop the image. */
            camera.putExtra("crop", "true");


            /** These provide the initial dimensions for X and Y. */
            camera.putExtra("outputX",600);
            camera.putExtra("outputY", 600);

            /** These provide the relative aspects. */
            camera.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            camera.putExtra("aspectY", 1);


            /** These I am unsure about. */
            camera.putExtra("scale", true);
            camera.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

**so by setting the aspects to 0 instead of 1,**

```
            /** These provide the relative aspects. */
            camera.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            camera.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
```

They become independent of each other...

Problem solved !

**FINAL CODE**

```
            Intent camera=new Intent();
            camera.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            camera.putExtra("crop", "true");
            camera.putExtra("outputX",600);
            camera.putExtra("outputY", 600);
            camera.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            camera.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            camera.putExtra("scale", true);
            camera.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

Comment: how to get cropped image ?