# Camera crashes due to crop code one line, how to crop in standard way

Tags: android, camera, crop

My app crashes due to `camera.putExtra("crop", "true");` Im assuming this is due to some stupid inconsistent vendor camera drivers or something... joys of fragmented market i guess.

How can i crop if this doesn't work? preferably have crop square on screen to guide user. Is there a standard ~99% proof method?

Comment: Like Kay said, it´s an Intent that calls an app, that is not installed on every device. What You can do is, catch the exception if it is not installed and hint the user to install that app.

Comment: is it crashing only for gallery picked image or both camera and gallery picked?

Comment: Thx Opiatefuchs. 
@ Vishwajit Palankar, i have a issue with Gallery option but i don't think its related, its crashing when the camera saves the image taken, no extra solves the issue but then how to crop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look at the below mentioned link.

[Android intent with multiple option i.e , Pick image from gallary and capture image using front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532914/android-intent-with-multiple-option-i-e-pick-image-from-gallary-and-capture-im)

if you won't go to intent use crop library

https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: thx - i used the first link, copied and pasted and tinkered with one or 2 things and boom. Getting to grips with an issue but working it and will update that post later

Answer (score 1):

There is no crop intent in Android !!

From https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

> > Many developers are calling startActivity() on an Intent with an action of com.android.camera.action.CROP. They are doing this to crop an image.
> >
> > This is a really bad idea.
> >
> > In this specific case, this Intent action is supported by the AOSP Camera app. That app does not exist on all devices. Devices lacking this app will not respond to this undocumented Intent action, and your app will crash.

Further reads: [Explanation of Android Code Camera Intent + Croping Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551074/explanation-of-android-code-camera-intent-croping-images)

In essence, the above intent will crash on some devices.

I bet if commonsware's Author see this post , he could explain it even better.

Answer (score 0):

> Im assuming this is due to some stupid inconsistent vendor camera drivers or something... joys of fragmented market i guess.

Primarily, it is because that is not part of the Android SDK. There is no requirement for any camera app to support random `Intent` extras.

> How can i crop if this doesn't work?

Use [a library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Or write your own image cropping engine.

Comment: It doesn't need to be rew for it to support random intents but it should return more than -1. And... Write a crop engine? So nobody has attempted to crop before?

Comment: @Fearghal: "It doesn't need to be rew for it to support random intents but it should return more than -1" -- you are welcome to attempt to force all camera app authors to adhere to your demands to honor random extras. "So nobody has attempted to crop before?" -- there are six libraries, at present, at [the link from my answer](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). You can tell that by clicking the link. *If* none of those libraries meet your requirements, *then* you will need to write your own image cropping code.

Comment: Oh your edited part - 'use a library' link is dead :(

Comment: @Fearghal: Both the link in the answer and in the comment work just fine. Your browser, or perhaps your Internet connection, is having some issue.